# Java Web application not sending Email on Ubuntu server

Tags: email, web-applications, playframework

My play framework web application sends automatically emails to user using Apache commons email library, everything works fine on my machine, but when I deploy it on an Ubuntu server it is unable to send email.

It throws exceptions like `org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.googlemail.com:465` (I also tried different configuration with smtp.google.mail port 465,25 and 587 with or without ssl and tls)
and `connection timed out`.

I starting to believe that is a problem of some configuration of my ubuntu server.

Any suggestion?

If i type ufw status command I receive status disabled.

Thanks

Comment: Try to see if you have the ports open by trying to connect to the gmail server by executing a telnet, just try to do the following: telnet smtp.googlemail.com 465

Comment: I tried and i keep receive telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable on all ports 25, 465, 587

Comment: I am going to close this question, because I found the solution. Basically my Server provider has a security configuration where SMTP is blocked. I asked them to unlock It.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to close this question, because I found the solution. Basically my Server provider (Scaleway) has a security configuration where SMTP is blocked. I asked them to unlock It.